# Prevent calls from being made on iPhone

Tags: iphone, parental-controls

My daughter of 18 months loves to play with my iPhone. I'm okay with her randomly rearranging the home screen, resetting highscores and such, but now she's discovered how to make calls from the contacts list, and explaining to work contacts why "I" called on a Sunday night is getting awkward... is there a parental controls setting or somesuch to lock the calling feature while leaving the rest of the phone available to her?

Comment: You could put the phone in Airplane Mode, but that would disable wireless networking also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could put the phone into Airplane mode, which will work until she figures out how to turn it off. (If she needs Internet access, you can re-enable wifi after putting it into Airplane mode.)

Comment: Great minds think alike :-)

Comment: You have priority -- it looks like you beat me to it by two seconds.

Comment: Only because you gave the fuller answer about WiFi.